# how to stop content from going behind absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css

Most of my content is inside a `<main>` element:

```
<main>
<h1>A nice big, long, long heading</h1>
<p>Lots of text</p>
</main>

main {
max-width:200px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0 20px;
}

h1 {
position:absolute;
max-width:300px;
padding-right:20px;
}
```

This acheives this:

[image]

The heading is wider than the main column: it protrudes out of the right hand edge - exactly what I want.

However the text below the heading is displayed behind the heading (because the heading has been taken out of normal flow).

I don't know if the heading will be one or two lines or wrap on to more lines.

Is there a way to get the text beneath the heading to be displayed below the heading (not behind it): to respect the height of the heading (as if it was in normal flow)?

Comment: Only if you know the height of the heading. Otherwise you need JS

Comment: If you are removing the `h1` element from the normal document flow so that it can overflow its parent, consider this alternative: https://jsfiddle.net/Lst702u3/ (keep the `h1` element in the flow, and allow parent to visibly overflow)

Comment: Thanks for your time, but as mentioned in the question, the heading should wrap, i.e. not have a fixed width. Unfortunately this suggestion doesn't work when changing the width to max-width.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```css
main {
max-width: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 20px;
background: blue;
height: 300px;

}

h1 {
position: relative;
width: 300px;
padding-right: 20px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
<h1>A nice big, long, long heading</h1>
<p>Lots of text Lots of textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots of textLots of text</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but the heading can't have a fixed width. As mentioned in the opening post the heading will wrap on to new lines when the browser window is smaller. Unfortuntely when width is changed to max-width this suggestion doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Set the position of main to relative. You can remove max-width on h1

```
main {
    max-width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

h1 {
    position:absolute;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

Comment: I want the heading to have a max-width greater than the main element. This is easy to acheive with the code in my opening question. The problem is  the text below the heading appears *behind* the heading (because the heading has been taken out of normal flow). I don't know the height of the heading cos' it will wrap on to more lines. Is there a way for the text below the heading to respect the height of the heading?

Comment: I don't think absolute position is necessary here, you can set the max-width of the main container to be equal to the max-width (300px) of the heading, then set the max-width of a every other child container to 200px, in this case your paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Ekwonye. I suspect I might have to do this, but I was hoping for a way to have my main container (containing most of the content: paragraphs, images, tables etc) centered on the screen - not off centered.